# Intersection multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $f=y^2-x^3$ and $g=y^3-x^7$. Calculate the intersection multiplicity of $f$ and $g$ at $(0,0)$.

I know the general technique for this (passing to the local ring) but I having difficulty with the fact that $3,7,2$ have no common factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the properties of intersection number can save much time for the
calculation of intersection numbers.
If $P$ is a point, two affine plane curves $F$ and $G$ have no common
components, then: (see section 3.3 in Fulton's algebraic curves)

1. $I(P,F\cap G)=I(F\cap (G+AF))$ for any $A\in k[X,Y]$;
2. $I(P,F\cap G)=m_p(F)m_P(G)$, when $F$ and $G$ have not tangent
   lines in common at $P$.
3. $I(P,F\cap GH)=I(P,F\cap G)+I(P,F\cap H)$ for $H\in k[X,Y]$.

Now, $P=(0,0)$,

$I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y^3-x^7)=I(P, y^2-x^3\cap
((y^3-x^7)-(y^2-x^3)x^4))$

$\quad =I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y^2)+I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y-x^4).$

And $I(P, y^2-x^3\cap y^2)=I(P,x^3\cap y^2)=3\times 2=6$.

$I(P, y^2-x^3\cap y-x^4)=I(P, y^2-x^3\cap
((y-x^4)-(y^2-x^3)x))$

$\quad =I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y(1-xy))=3$.

Thus $9=6+3$ is the
desired number.

---

$I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y(1-xy))=I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y)+I(P,y^2-x^3\cap (1-xy))$,

$I(P,y^2-x^3\cap y)=I(P,-x^3\cap y)=3$ and $I(P,y^2-x^3\cap (1-xy))=0$ ($P$ is not the zero of $1-xy$).

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the last bit. Isn't the multiplicity of $y^2-x^3$ equal to 2 (because that is the lowest power) and the multiplicity of $y(1-xy)$ equal to 2?

Comment: Dear @user137090, see the update.

Comment: @user137090. I have come across an example when the point of intersection is not (0,0). $f=x+y-2$ and $g=x^2+y^2-2$ intersect at (1,1). How do we compute the multiplicity in the way you describe? Thanks

Comment: is it ok in such a case to translate by (1,1) so it is equivalent to finding intersection multiplicity of $x+y$ and $x^2+2x+y^2+2y$ at (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Please take a look at Fulton's book "algebraic curve"

Answer (score 0):

I think you no longer need an answer, but I’d like to write something here since it may help some other students.

We need four lemmas here(You can find them in lecture 2 of [Andreas Gathmann’s notes in Plane Algebraic Curves](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/curves-2018/curves-2018.pdf)):

Lemma (1): For any three plane curves F, G, H, $$\mu_p(F, G)=\mu_p(F, G+FH)$$

Lemma (2): For any three plane curves F, G, H, $$\mu_p(F, GH)=\mu_p(F, G)+\mu_p(F, H)$$

Lemma (3): $\mu_p(F, G)\ge 1$ iff $P\in F\cap G$.

Lemma (4): $\mu_p(F, G)=1$ iff $<F, G>=I_p$, where $I_p =\{f/g: f, g\in K[x, y], f(P)=0, g(P)\neq 0\}$.

Now we can compute $\mu_0(y^2-x^3, y^3-x^7)$.

$\begin{align}\mu_0(y^2-x^3, y^3-x^7)\overset{by (1)}{=}\mu_0(y^2-x^3, y^3-x^7-y(y^2-x^3))=\mu_0(y^2-x^3, x^3y-x^7)\overset{by (2)}{=}\mu_0(y^2-x^3, x^3)+\mu_0(y^2-x^3, y-x^4)\overset{by (1)}{=}\mu_0(y^2-x^3+x^3, x^3)+\mu_0(y^2-x^3-y(y-x^4), y-x^4))=\mu_0(y^2, x^3)+\mu_0(x^4y-x^3, y-x^4)\overset{by (2), (2), respectively}{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=}6\mu_0(y, x)+\mu_0(x^3, y-x^4)+\mu_0(xy-1, y-x^4)\overset{by (4), (1), (3), respectively}{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=}6+\mu_0(x^3, y-x^4+x(x^3))+0=6+\mu_0(x^3, y)\overset{by (2)}{=}6+3\mu_0(x, y)\overset{by (4)}{=}6+3=9\end{align}.$

Comment: Trying to fit all of that math in one line is really rough for formatting and readability. Please consider breaking it up in to different lines and using connecting phrases instead of trying to \overset your explanations above the equals signs.